# При запросе выводит по два одинаковых значения

Tags: php

```
     $conn = new mysqli('local', 'admin', '1234', 'bdata');

    if ($conn1->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
    }    
    $query = "select * from tabl0";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
print_r($row)."<br>\n";

}
```

Делаю запрос в php, выводит

```
  array
    { 
         [0]=>'1 значение';
         [1 Столбец]=>'1 значение';
    }
```

Что необходимо в запросе поменять, чтоб не выводил [0]. В самой базе localhost/phpmyadmin/sql.php, нет столбиков с 0 названием, он от кудато подгружает их.
ps MariaDB -mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения данных, вы используете функцию `mysql_fetch_array($result)`. 
Для того чтобы получить только ассоциативный массив, используйте функцию  `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.

Answer (score 1):

при выполнении запроса в базу данных в функции `mysqli_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQLI_BOTH ] )` 
нужно указать необязательный параметр `$result_type = MYSQLI_ASSOC`

в зависимости от его значения массив возвращается с именами полей, порядковыми номерами столбцов или и тем и тем, как у вас в вопросе 
потому что это значение по умолчанию

описание функции тут -> 
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен как идет работа с mariadb, но в mysql это решает через fetch_assoc:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Если говорить про PDO, то нужно установить  $fetch_style = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Для примера: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Извлечение всех значений первого столбца */
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 0);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Список $fetch_style:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php